# How to "fix" the size of Windows Button Item in xfce4-panel 4.10.1

Tags: xfce

just finished installing ubuntu 13.10 with xubuntu Desktop and i tried to have a "windows 7" look (I know, some of you will hate me but after 15 years using windows, it is hard to loose the habit of the bottom bar and the start menu.
However, after fallowing the PCWORLD guide how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7 **Installing and customizing Xfce**, I would like to fix the Panel I have set up.
Even if I followed the guide entirely, when I added the Window Buttons Item, I realized that it has a dynamic size and doesn't look like the guide....all the Items "on the right side" (Separator, Notification Area, Indicator Plugin, Show Desktop) do not stay fixed but they move from left to right and right to left depending how many "windows" I open.:

[image: Bar 1]
[image: Bar 2]

Anyone of you has an Idea how to fix the size so I will have my bar looking like the windows on with the Start button on the left, the clock and plugins on the right and then the middle empty when windows are not opened?

Thank you

Comment: Funny thing is that it worked on 12.04 but i had to upgrade as the 12.04 didn't work with my NAS (had to mount it manually every time). I like Ubuntu but it as soon as you "fix something" you get issues somewhere else :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved finding a post on another Forum....
"add a separator to the panel just to the left of the items you want to have on the right. Set it to expand and also make it transparent so it isn't seen."

Comment: Not helpful, without a link